# Edit a line and create it if it's not found

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

Basically i got a "database", and a function in my script to install applications. So this function down here searches for:

```
is-program-installed=
```

and happens "1" when "program" installation finishes:

```
is-program-installed= 1
```

but what happens if the line is not found and i want that function to write one?

```
function dbmarktrue () {

table=${1?Usage: dbmarktrue $editdbtable}

sed -e "/^is-$table-installed=/ s/.$/1/" -i database.txt
}
```

Comment: *but what if the line "is-$program-installed=" doesn't already exists?

Comment: the function goes and edits a string in database.txt
but how can i do to make the function to create the string if it's not found?

Comment: Don't use `sed`? Use `awk` or `grep`+`echo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go through the file and perform the replacement; if it happens, set a flag. And finally, after the whole file was processed, print it if such flag was not set:

```
awk -v replace="is-program-installed=1" '
       $0 == "is-program-installed=" {$0=replace; seen=1}1;
       END {if (!seen) print replace}' a
```

#### Test

It was not present:

```
$ cat a
hello
$ awk -v replace="is-program-installed=1" '$0 == "is-program-installed=" {$0=replace; seen=1}1; END {if (!seen) print replace}' a
hello
is-program-installed=1
```

It was present:

```
$ cat a
hello
is-program-installed=
$ awk -v replace="is-program-installed=1" '$0 == "is-program-installed=" {$0=replace; seen=1}1; END {if (!seen) print replace}' a
hello
is-program-installed=1
```

---

As usual, `awk` to replace the original file you can redirect the output to a temporary file and then move to the original:

```
awk '...' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

By using `&&` we make sure the `mv` command is not executed if the `awk` exits with an error.